# Mssql update query returns row count but not updating actual records

Tags: sql-server

I am running below query individually on sql server database, running on version 2014.

Trying to execute below query to update 2 records. When I execute script, it returns rowcount =2 but records remain with old values always.

There are no triggers defined on table. for further checking I added output clause in my update script and surprisingly it is returning old value for column of inserted table.

```
update MemberDataImport set IsInsertStatus=3579346798476 
where LastName is null;

update MemberDataImport set IsInsertStatus=3579346798476 
output inserted.IsInsertStatus
where LastName is null;

update MemberDataImport set IsInsertStatus=2
output inserted.IsInsertStatus
where LastName is null;

update MemberDataImport set IsInsertStatus=100
output inserted.IsInsertStatus
where LastName is null;
```

no matter what values I am updating it always returns 1 as output which is currently stored in table for column 'IsInsertStatus'

First time ever I am seeing this kind of problem.

Comment: just to try ..have you put a COMMIT TRANSACTION at the end of the script?

Comment: check the range of your `IsInsertStatus` if int you cannot insert the value 3579346798476

Comment: Why don't you use schema? You may have 2 tables MemberDataImport, one in dbo schema, another in user default schema, so you update one table but then check another table

Answer (score 0):

> no matter what values I am updating i**t always returns 1 as output**
>   which is currently stored in table for column 'IsInsertStatus'

Here is the repro:

```
declare @MemberDataImport table (IsInsertStatus bit, lastname varchar(100))
insert into @MemberDataImport (IsInsertStatus) values (10)

update @MemberDataImport set IsInsertStatus=2
output inserted.IsInsertStatus
where LastName is null;
```

That is because if IsInsertStatus is `bit`.